# Anydesk and X Server problems

Tags: 16.04, xorg, xserver

First-time poster here so do pardon me if I don't usse the correct terms. I'm trying to set up a screen in my local computer for my headless VM instance in Google Compute Engine using Anydesk (I think it's similar to teamviewer).

So when I try to run the program. I get the problem:

```
(py35) jamsawamsa@jamsa-fastai:~/downloads$ anydesk
No UTF-8. Trying to change locale.
Locale sucessfully changed.
No protocol specified

(anydesk:10995): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
No UTF-8. Trying to change locale.
Locale sucessfully changed.
No protocol specified

(anydesk:10997): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
No protocol specified
```

I would've posted this at the anydesk help forums, but they don't seem too responsive and this seems like a problem with the display mappings in my VM.

Some solutions I've tried -

```
export DISPLAY=:0
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

but both give me the same issue as above. Any help's greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
export DISPLAY=:0; anydesk --silent
```

This works for me. I run this command with a non-root user.

OS: Centos 7.4

Anydesk server version: 4.0.1